# What are the alternatives to using "FindObjectsOfType"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As of right now I am using Unity with C#. My Code are as follows:

```
    var buttons = FindObjectsOfType<DefenderButton>();

    foreach (DefenderButton button in buttons) // color unselect resets back color
    {
        button.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color32(41, 41, 41, 255); 
    }
```

What are the alternatives to using `FindObjectsOfType`?

Comment: In which use-case exactly? There are lots of different ways of how to obtain certain object references .... use other version of `Find`, store them all in a serialized List ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the same tag for all GameObjects that contain the class `DefenderButton` in Unity or use the property `tag` in `GameObject` class to set the tag. For this answer i will use tag `any`.
After you set the tag you can do the following:

```
foreach (GameObject obj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("any"))
{
    foreach (DefenderButton button in obj.GetComponents<DefenderButton>())
    {
       button.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color32(41, 41, 41, 255); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, my attempt this  - GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Defender Button").GetComponents<DefenderButton>(); - It didnt work. So i have to loop through the game objects with tag and then loop again through script of the game object.

Answer (score 0):

Find object with a `string` property
`GameObject.Find()`
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

Finds objects you marked with a certain tag 
`GameObject.FindWithTag()`
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

And lastly (that i know of) you can just traverse the `GameObject` hierarchy  and 'Find' stuff, like for example (pseudo-code just to give you an idea):

Lets say your gameobjects are arranged like so:

```
- obj 0
  - Obj1
    - obj1A
    - obj2B
  - Obj2
```

If you're in `Obj2`, you can do the following:

```
var obj2B = transform.parent // obj0
              .Children.First() // obj1
                 .Children.Last() // obj2B
```

Comment: Here I have "var buttons = FindObjectsOfType<DefenderButton>();", it finds all of the GameObjects with DefenderButton classes in it and put in "buttons"  -  The third one would work but lets say I want to use FindWithTag as follows defenderButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Defender Button").GetComponent<DefenderButton>(); How do I use this?

Comment: Getting an error when I put  "foreach (DefenderButton button in defenderButton)" - foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type "DefenderButton" because "DefenderButton" does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Comment: Ive tried but print first GameObject as stated "Note: This method returns the first GameObject it finds with the specified tag. If a scene contains multiple active GameObjects with the specified tag, there is no guarantee this method will return a specific GameObject." - DefenderButton[] defenderButtons = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Defender Button").GetComponents<DefenderButton>();
        foreach (DefenderButton button in defenderButtons) // color unselect resets back color
        {
            button.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color32(41, 41, 41, 255); 
        }

Comment: well in your question you asked for alternatives to `FindObjectsOfType` so i answered with all alternatives to that function. .Find(..) is for a single object, if you need multiple you can use OfType like you mentioned in your question or you could use WithTag. did you read the documentation? also from your questions here i could deduce that the code you provided in the question did not work? is there something wrong with it? why does .FindOfType not work for you?

Comment: Thanks but FindObjectsOfType is different to FindObjectOfType. Yes I'm using multiple and I don't wanna use FindObjectsOfType because it's slow in fetching.